# recompile an msi with silent switch

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-installer

all i need is to add a silent switch to an msi and recompile it as an msi or exe. I have the MSI SDK but admittedly i'm over my head with this sort of scripting and don't know where to begin

Comment: Just as BriGuy answered below, there are built-in flags for MSI installation. If you want a completely silent install you would use "MyInstall.msi /qn" for no UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install the MSI file silently using MSIEXEC with the following flags:

> /quiet - quiet mode, no user interaction
>
> /q[n|b|r|f]        Sets user interface level
>  n - No UI
>  b - Basic
>   UI
>  r - Reduced UI
>  f - Full UI (default)

Or you just create an installer that does not display a GUI during install.

Comment: Maybe i should rephrase the question. I need to deploy an MSI to remote users, and i want it to work silently and automatically. So i'd like a way to have the MSI with those switches built in.

Comment: @acme64 - if you are deploying the MSI via GPO, if you make it assigned it will automatically install silently.

Comment: No its just hosting on our website. I went ahead and just made an autoit exe with the switches in there. First code ever! thanks for the lead though

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works like a charm every time:

`msiexec.exe /qb- /l*vx  %LogPath%\<file>.log REBOOT=ReallySuppress UILevel=67 ALLUSERS=2 /I filename.msi`